# Lazy loading. No component factory found. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I create page with simple modal window using ng2-bootstrap library. It looks like:

**action-list.component.html**

```
<a class="btn-setting"  (click)="dangerModal.show()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

<div bsModal #dangerModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-danger" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="dangerModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="dangerModal.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="delete()">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

But when I clicked trash icon *(first href)* I got error:

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for ModalBackdropComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.es5.js:3202)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.es5.js:3267)
    at ComponentLoader.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-bootstrap/component-loader/component-loader.class.js.ComponentLoader.attach (component-loader.class.js:42)
    at ModalDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-bootstrap/modal/modal.component.js.ModalDirective.showBackdrop (modal.component.js:195)
    at ModalDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-bootstrap/modal/modal.component.js.ModalDirective.show (modal.component.js:102)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ActionListComponent.html:102)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12047)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13506)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13094)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8659)
```

I found info that may by missing entryComponents annotation in my module for showing component, so I tried add:

**action.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    //...
    imports: [
        //...
        ModalModule,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ModalBackdropComponent
    ]
})
```

But i still have the same error.

My question: **Can the error be caused by lazy loading my module? If so, how can I get around this issue?** If you know answer, let me explain how does entryComponents work, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. I solved the problem. In my case,  import ModalModule was missing in main app module. The solution looks like this:

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        //...
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ],
    //...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone :)

Comment: So it's not actually lazy loaded but loaded with the main app... What a headache. I have been dealing with this for a while now. The ionic team had better start working on improving this corner of the framework. Lazy loading is starting to get more and more cumbersome by the minute, and it is NOT comprehensive at all

Comment: did you find any way to do this without adding it to the main app module?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, forgetting to add the `NgbModule` to my lazy loaded module imports caused the same error. So, the solution template is the following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
    ModalDlgComponent,
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
    ModalDlgComponent,
    ...
  ]
})
export class MyLazyLoadedModule {}
```