# Open Angular Bootstrap modal from component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-module

I'm trying to set up a simple modal using angular bootstrap. But I'm running to this error :

```
 "ERROR Error: No component factory found for ModalContentComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError"
```

I've imported the module but still unable to get this working. I've started with the documentation [HERE](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#modal-directive) and also looked at this StackOverflow question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783289/lazy-loading-no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycompo).

Here is my app.module :

```
import { FormPoster } from './services/form-poster.service';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/buttons';
import { RatingModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/rating';
import { AddGameComponent } from './add-game/add-game.component';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
EmployeeComponent,
EmployeeTitlePipe,
EmployeeListComponent,
EmployeeCountComponent,
HomeComponentComponent,
PageNotFoundComponent,
AddEmployeeComponent,
AddGameComponent,        
],

imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
 FormsModule,
 HttpModule,
 ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
 RatingModule.forRoot(),
 ModalModule.forRoot(),
 DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
 ],
 providers: [EmployeeService, FormPoster],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ModalContentComponent` inside `entryComponent` in your module file.

Like following :

```
entryComponents: [
    ModalContentComponent
]
```

Comment: I did try that and the error received was "Uncaught Error: ModalContentComponent can not be used as an entry component"

Answer (score 0):

You should add your component to **@NgModule** and **entryComponents**

Step 1 : Import the component into the app.module.ts

```
import { CatalogDetailsComponent, ModalContentComponent } from './catalog-details/catalog-details.component'
```

Step 2 : Add imported module to **@NgModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalContentComponent 
  ],
```

Step 3 : Add **entryComponents** below **@NgModule** if it is not there and add imported component there also

```
  entryComponents: [
    ModalContentComponent
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the component to the module as an `entryComponents` AND in `declarations`.